hiding a wordpress blog post category from the main archive page
I'm trying to work out how to hide a particular category (id=89) from my wordpress blog archive page. I want to be able to use specific blog posts with this category on another part of the site but i don't want them to appear in any of the main archive pages (as a category link or show the posts themselves via the archive page). I have the following code on my page but i don't know where and what to add to it to hide this id:
        <h3>Categories</h3>
        <?php
        $categories = get_categories( array(
            'hide_empty' => 1,
        ) );
         
        foreach( $categories as $category ) {
        
        // print_r($category);
        
        $category_link = get_category_link( $category->term_id ); 
        ?>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $category_link; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a></li>
        
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        
        </ul>
        </div>
```


So - wrap the content of the foreach loop into an if conditional then? if (89 !== $category->term_id)

It sounds like you better define a custom taxonomy for that other use of category 89, rather than using the same taxonomy (category) for both things. Generally speaking relying on a specific ID for anything is a bad practice and should be avoided.

For the category list, modify your code like this:
<h3>Categories</h3>
<?php
$categories = get_categories(array(
    'hide_empty' => 1,
    'exclude' => array(89) // Exclude category ID 89
));
 
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $category_link = get_category_link($category->term_id); 
    ?>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url($category_link); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($category->name); ?></a></li>
    </ul>
    <?php
}
?>
</div>

To also exclude posts from this category in your archive pages, add this code to your theme's functions.php file
function exclude_category_from_archive($query) {
if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
    if ($query->is_archive() || $query->is_home()) {
        $query->set('cat', '-89'); // The minus sign excludes the 

category
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_from_archive');

If you need to exclude multiple categories, you can modify the arrays like this:
'exclude' => array(89, 90, 91) // For the category list

$query->set('cat', '-89,-90,-91') // For the archive pages

Thanks. Not quite getting there but i think it may have to do with the other code on the page. Thanks anyway.

You can simply exclude the category in your get_categories args:
<h3>Categories</h3>
  <?php
  $categories = get_categories( array(
      'hide_empty' => 1,
      'exclude' => 89,
  ) );
   
  foreach( $categories as $category ) {
  
  // print_r($category);
  var_dump($category);
  
  $category_link = get_category_link( $category->term_id ); 
  ?>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="<?php echo $category_link; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a></li>
  
  <?php
  }
  ?>
  
  </ul>
  </div>


Thanks. Not quite getting there but i think it may have to do with the other code on the page. Thanks anyway.
